# Inline ngRepeat over array of objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to write an `ng-repeat` with an array of objects, defining the array in the ng-repeat attribute, but for some reason it just repeats the output indefinitely.
I've boiled it down to the issue being to do with the last part; doing it inline.

```
<span ng-repeat="item in [{test:'a'}, {test:'b'}, {test:'c'}]">{{item.test}}</span>
```

[image: result of above on my server]

A bunch of `Error: [$rootScope:infdig]` error's turn up in the console.
Interestingly, although I'm running 1.2, no matter which angular version I choose in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhgzdjjz/), it renders it just fine.

[image: result of jsfiddle testing]

But the console in jsfiddle is still flooded with errors `Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`, doing this not only for arrays of objects, but arrays of arrays (test5).

My attempt at a workaround, test5 in that fiddle, saving the var, is really interesting because if you comment out the ng-repeat, [it saves the scope variable fine](https://jsfiddle.net/mhgzdjjz/2/) without error.
Yet when you try to use that variable, [that is where it dies](https://jsfiddle.net/mhgzdjjz/3/). It's interesting because that is essentially test3, which goes off without a hitch.

So it must be an issue with the one thing I want to do, have the [variable come from the html](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig) (instead of pre-existing in the js). So to kill the digest loop I tried switching the fiddle to v1.4 to use [one time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding) and [it still fails](https://jsfiddle.net/mhgzdjjz/4/) (console error wise).

<sub>Other people [seem to have hit the issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/2466), but fixed it in their own library instead of reporting it upstream</sub>

Is there any way for me to get this working properly?

Comment: do you call `$evalAsync()` or a similar function in your `ng-repeat`?

Comment: nope. The fiddles are right there, and that code snippet [at the start of the question] is all you need to see it happening. The only reason it displays 'right' in the fiddle is because the digest depth is capped so it errors right after the first iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this code.

```
<!--what I actually want to work-->
  <span ng-init="test10 = [{'text':'but'}, {'text':'this'}, {'text':'refuses'}, {'text':'to'}, {'text':'work'}]"></span>
  <span ng-repeat="item in test10">{{item.text}} </span>
```

With ng-init you can set a scope variable from the view.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I can't believe I forgot about init, that's delicious. Thanks, [works perfectly](https://jsfiddle.net/mhgzdjjz/5/). Sucks that you can't put the `ng-init` in the same div, but at least I can make it a little cleaner as it allows multiple declarations per init